# how is orbit of a set different from orbit of an element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am currently learning about orbits and stabilizers. I know the definitions of both but I get confused if it's done on a set.

For example,
If $G$ is a group and $S$ is a set of subgroups of $G$,

$g \cdot H = gHg^{-1}$ is a left action.

So using this action, if $G = S_4$ and $H = V_4$

$Orb(V_4)$

$= \{ g \cdot V_4 \in V_4 : g \in S_4 \}$

$= \{ gV_4g^{-1} \in V_4: g \in S_4 \}$

$Stab(V_4)$

$ = \{g \in S_4: g \cdot V_4 = V_4 \}$

$ = \{g \in S_4: g V_4 g^{-1} = V_4\} $

$ = \{g \in S4: g V_4 = V_4 g\}$

Is this correct? And is there a way to simplify these more?

Also, I don't get intuitively what orbit and stabilizer of a set is. For an element, I think of it as where the element $s$ can go to by action of G and what doesn't change $s$ respectively.

What about for a set?

Comment: Some familiar ideas can be used in terms of this particular action: $H$ is normal if (and only if) the orbit of $H$ is just $H$ (in which case the stabilizer is all of $G$). Note as well that the normalizer in $G$ of $H$ is just the stabilizer of $H$. In this example, $V_4$ might not be the best subgroup to look at, you might want to look at the orbit of $H = \{e, (1\ 2)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is correct.

When $G$ acts on its set of subgroups by conjugation, we think of subgroups as *points* not sets. So its the same exact way of thinking about orbits and stabilizers.